# Mean and variance of likelihood function wrt data

Tags: distributions, variance, expected-value, likelihood

In my [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508771/likelihood-as-random-function-wrt-data) I asked about the distribution of the likelihood function as a random function depending on the sample of data we have. It seems that this distribution depends on the distribution of data, and is not of a standard form, so there's no general answer to this question.

However, if we have some distribution of the data, what are the techniques we can use to find information about the distribution of the likelihood, like the mean, variance, mgf etc?

This my calculation:

The expected log likelihood, $\mathbb{E}_x[\log P(x_i|\theta)]$, would simply be the log likelihood of $\theta$ for the expected data $\mu_x = \mathbb{E}[x|\theta^*]$ where $P(x|\theta^*)$ is the true distribution of $x$. I.e., $\log P(\mu_x|\theta)$.

The above calculation assumes you can pass the expectation through the function "$\log P$" which I'm not entirely sure about.

For variance, it suffices to calculate $\text{Var}(\log P(x_i|\theta))$ for iid data $x = \{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$. This is because the iid assumption allows summing of variances of $L_x(\theta)= \sum_{i=1}^n \log P(x_i|\theta)$:
$$\text{Var}(\sum_{i=1}^n \log P(x_i|\theta)) = \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(\log P(x_i|\theta))$$ But what is $\text{Var}(\log P(x_i|\theta))$?

Comment: Are you assuming that you have an analytic description of $P(x \vert \theta)$?

Comment: @Dave Ah yes I should have mentioned that -- suppose the underlying model is known

Comment: Does the mean of a likelihood function have any particular meaning? I know that the maximum is usually of interest, but I have not seen the mean being considered directly. The nature of a likelihood function is not at all like that of a population distribution.

Comment: @MichaelLew is this something that's studied? and can you explain your last sentence?

Comment: I've written a bit about likelihood functions and likelihood in this arXived paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.08394

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no special tricks for handling this problem.

When I ran into a similar problem before, I ended up using the method of [steepest descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent) to find approximate solutions.

If $P(x \vert \theta)$ can sensibly be written as  $P(x \vert \theta) = e^{f(x; \theta)}$, then

$$
E\left[ \log P \right] = \int f(x; \theta) e^{f(x; \theta)} dx 
$$

then if $P(x\vert \theta)$ is unimodal, $f(x; \theta)$ has one maximum and one can usually approximate the integrand using the method of steepest descent.

One can do the same thing for $E\left[ (\log P)^2 \right]$.

These two moments then allow you to derive the mean and variance of the the distribution for the sum of the log-likelihood of an ensemble composed of independent samples from the distribution.  And in the limit where the number of samples in the ensemble is large, this distribution will typically tend to a Gaussian (central limit theorem; usual disclaimers apply).

Comment: wait, why is the integrand being approximated? If we assume $P(x|\theta)$ is known then the integrand is known... on the other hand the integral itself can approximated with some numerical method if it is intractable. And the calculations you show apply to a single datapoint $x_i$, right? $E[log P]$ and $E[(logP)^2]$ should each be a sum of their values for all datapoints. Thanks for the reply btw!

Comment: @edges900 If you can do it exactly analytically or want to do it via numerical evaluation, go for it.  I just mentioned that I found it useful to use the method of steepest descent when I had a similar problem.  You can also do it by using a sample that is drawn from $P(x\vert \theta)$ -- this corresponds to using a Monte Carlo approach to approximate the integral.